# wordpress admin panel 504 Gateway Timeout category

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

i find this error when i enter wp-admin category. the problem can have this 250 category. the problem is happening occasionally I would appreciate if you help

```
504 Gateway Timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be many reasons. one of them is the lack of server cpu. try this
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/ow-to-fix-the-504-gateway-timeout-error-in-wordpress/